# Mockito ElasticSearch Unit test in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito in Spring Boot in order to write a Unit Test that "imitates" a call to my ElasticSearch instance. Now since in Unit Testing you are not supposed to bother external resources, and thus using Mockito, I have my ElasticSearch instance stopped. The problem is that my UnitTest keeps trying to connect to my ElasticSearch instance so it fails by saying "Connection refused". Here is my test:

```
import com.google.common.net.HttpHeaders;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.util.Base64Utils;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ElasticSearchConnectionTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@Value("${elasticsearch.user}")
private String user;

@Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
private String password;

private String myjson = "{ \"order\": \n" + "{ \n" + "\"id\":\"dbId\",\n" + "\"status\":\"completed\",\n" + "} \n" + "}";

@Test
public void contextLoads() throws Exception {

    this.mvc.perform(post("/order")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(myjson)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " +Base64Utils.encodeToString((user+":"+password).getBytes())))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
  }
}
```

The error message says: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

I am using using [Java Low Level Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low.html) for calling calls to ElasticSearch

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: let's clarify what do you want to test.

1. If it's a test, where you want to make a call to your service endpoint and underneath it will save some information in Elastic instance - it is more like an integration, not a unit test. 
   For integration test purposes, it is more useful to instantiate Spring boot application (or a part of it, related to Elastic communication) along with a test version of the elastic instance, and then make a call to your service and assert that as a result, the data got into elasticsearch. 
   For these purposes, you can use [ElasticSearch in docker container](https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot#embedded-elasticsearch) which will run in test scope before Application Context initialization and allow you to test all communications with it from the Spring boot service.
2. If it's a test for checking how service handles HTTP POST request for saving some data in Elastic - take a look on using @WebMvcTest - which under the hood will not instantiate the whole application, but only start part for the specific Controller. [Web Tests](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your service logic and emulate the real call against elastic-search, you can create a stub of elastic-search with wiremock. (Note that this sounds more like an integration test).

In a unit test you usually want to test your code implementation against other units of your code and in a integration test you should test your whole service against external dependencies.